# Magento 2 - Discount on Price with FPT and VAT not working

Tags: magento2, tax, discount

We are facing an issue on Magento 2.2.5 regarding discount on product price.
Here is the use-case:
I have a product with Base Price = 18€, Tier Price (I'm working with Customer groups) = 7.23€, FPT = 2.8€ and VAT = 22%
The price is 12.24€ for this product ( (7.23+2.8)*1.22 = 12.2366), everything is fine so far.
Please note that in the configuration, we show the product price tax included on the catalog and the checkout.
I have a coupon which apply 20% discount this product.

Here is my configuration for tax under Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax
[image]

When using this coupon on the shopping cart, the discount amount is as follow
[image]
While we expect to have 2.44€ of discount.

I cannot even explain the output since it does not make sense to me.

Thanks for your help !

/T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its coming from your tier price of 7.23 x 1.22 x 0.2 = 1.76 (the FPT is being ignored as you would really expect).

Comment: Hi there, do you mean that the FPT is being ignored in the discount calculation? Is there a way to include it ?

Comment: Fixed price tax is exactly that, its not based on sale value. If you really want to discount the FPT as well then just move the FPT cost into the product cost. You will need to be sure of your margins etc doing that though!

Comment: Great, didn't know that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, I've browsed around and found this [link](https://www.mage-world.com/blog/how-to-config-fixed-product-taxes-fpt-on-magento-2.html) which states:  it can be discounted. Can you advise? It seems to contradict your statement.

Comment: Adding the FPT to the subtotal will allow discounting of the whole order (excluding carriage) as discount will be on subtotal. I was assuming you wanted to apply a discount on a single item.

Comment: Ok, so in this case, how can I get the expected result through the Magento configuration ?